# Collecting geometric network distances and updating field with these distances for whole feature class?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.5, geometric-network

I have a geometric network representing a golf course irrigation system. The pump house is the only source and each irrigation head is a sink. I want to update a field in the heads fc ([Dist_from_Pump]) based on each head's distance from the pumphouse. I suspect this will be a Python solution, which I'm fine with, but how can I iterate over all of the heads, place a flag at each head, and then trace the network for a distance?

Or is there a different/better way?

I'm thinking something like:

```
    for head in heads:
      dist = [trace distance from head to pump]
      # then use an update cursor to add these distances to the attributes table. But I don't know how to get these distances from arcpy.
```

I'm using ArcMap 10.5

Answer (score 1):

So, I had to find a workaround to this issue. You would think that it would be easy to calculate distances of network features from a given point and it is, if all you want to do is view that distance. If you need to update a field based on this distance, here's how I did it:

1. Make copies of your geometric network features and import them to a new gdb.
2. Create a new **network dataset** with these features.
3. Use the network analyst toolbar to calculate routes using the start point as your facility and any or all end points as incidents. Calculate routes.
4. The routes features now have the distance attribute associated with them, but I needed this data in my point feature class.
5. Use the Generate Points Along Lines tool. Set the interval to a large number, longer than any of your routes will be, so there are no points along the routes other than at the ends. ENABLE ENDPOINTS.
6. The result is each route has two points--a start and stop. The start points all coincided at the same spot, so I deleted them all in an edit session. This left the data I wanted in a point feature class where each point was exactly snapped to the irrigation head I needed it to be on.
7. The only thing left to do is to transfer the route length attribute from the route point features to the irrigation head point features.
8. I used a custom Python tool to do this, but there are other ways. I have shared my custom tool in a shared Google drive here: [Spatial Attributes Update Tool](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QmwC2rXYaC5G2qwrlcItNMKSRHzn3pWh/view?usp=sharing). It is saved in an ArcMap 10 toolbox. I made this a few months ago and it comes in handy quite often. Feel free to use/modify it.

The tool updates a field in a target feature class from a field in a source feature class based on a spatial relationship/overlap type.